# Open a document in Office via HTTPS

Tags: office365, office-interop, office-js

I want to integrate a web based document management app with some office suite (preferrably Office 360)

I want to open Excel and Word documents from the browser and they should get saved back to the server via HTTPS.

The "open with" feature of browsers already allows for the opening, but how to add save featues?

Do I have to write an add-in or is there some Office 360 API that allows integration of "Office online" right into my wrb app?

Are there some other (JS based?) office suites that allow some better integration?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on your scenario, but I*think* you might need the REST APIs called Microsoft Graph. Take a look: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/

Answer (score 1):

you can do it from your add-in or from your web app. You need to use the graphAPI for this, check out the OneDrive API here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/onedrive

Comment: Same here. We want to load our own document directly from the OfficeJS integration in our Word addin.